# Replace all non printable characters except newline characters

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I want to replace all non printable characters, especially emojis from a text but want to retain the newline characters like `\n` and `\r`

I currently have this for escaping the non printable characters but it escapes `\n` and `\r` also:

```
preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $value);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[:print:]` is a POSIX character class for printable chars. If you use it in a negated character class, you can further add characters that you do not want to match with this pattern, i.e. you can use

```php
preg_replace('/[^\r\n[:print:]]/', '', $value)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/6q4Ym):

```php
$value = "One\tline\r\nThe second line";
echo preg_replace('/[^\r\n[:print:]]/', '', $value);
// => Oneline
//    The second line
```

The `[^\r\n[:print:]]` pattern matches all chars but printable, CR and LF chars.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea for a regex to "match something, but not when something else" is to first match the "something else" and then instruct the engine to skip it.

So something like...

```
preg_replace('/[\r\n](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[[:^print:]]/', '', $value);
```

This matches newline characters, and then discards the match. Any other non-printable characters are still matched by the second half, and replaced with the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do it:

```
preg_replace('/(?![\r\n])[[:^print:]]/', '', $value);
```

- `(?![\r\n])` - make sure the next char is not `\r` nor `\n`
- `[[:^print:]]` - capture the non-printable char

---

An alternate solution with reversed logic to achieve the same goal would like this:

```
preg_replace('/(?=[^\r\n])[[:^print:]]/', '', $value);
```